# Same Length Sql on Local and Production

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql  local and on production servers which is of same length. When I test sql on local it takes about 2 seconds to run and when i run the same thing on production or server it takes about 7 seconds to run.

Why so much difference?

Comment: What database server are you running on?  Oracle?  MSSQL?  MySQL?

Comment: If you're running the query using SSMS, have you tried comparing the plans produced by clicking "Include Actual Execution Plan" on the toolbar and executing the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the primary factor responsible for variation of SQL response time (especially when running the same query a few times in a row) is caching. Actually, there may be several caching effects at play at the same time:

1. Code caching (next time you issue the same query you won't have to do the hard parse -- saves time and resources)
2. Data caching, first of all    
   a) database-level caching (use of buffer cache)  
   but also  
   b) OS-level caching  
   or even  
   c) hardware-level caching

You can determine what exactly is going on by enabling autotrace and analyzing its output. If the first time you see a lot of recursive calls, and none (or much less) subsequently, that tells you about code caching (cursor sharing preventing you from parsing every time). If the first time you see a lot of physical reads, but much fewer subsequently, then it's database buffer cache at play. If the number of physical reads stays the same, but elapsed time changes, then it could be low-level data caching (OS or hardware).

There are, of course, other factors that may affect elapsed time -- such as database workload -- but if you are observing this over a short period of time, then it's probably not them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more ways to get this fixed, what you do is run the proc through cache tables it will make it faster, or just indexed it